# Selective labeling for ggplot lines

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, label, line-plot

**General Goal:** Use ggplot to selectively label only lines whose last points are above a certain y value.

**Potential Functions/Packages:** I'm aware of the `geom_text()` function and directlabels package but I can't identify a way in their documentation to selectively label lines in the way I described above.

**Sample Data**

```
ID <- c(rep("ID1", 5), rep("ID2", 5), rep("ID3", 5), rep("ID4", 5), rep("ID5", 5))
Y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
       10, 20, 30, 40, 1, 
       5, 10, 15, 10, 60, 
       50, 30, 20, 25, 10,
       20, 25, 30, 35, 50)
Year <- c(rep(seq(2000 ,2004), 5))
DATA <- data.frame(ID, Year, Y)
```

**Plot Data**

```
ggplot(data=DATA, aes(Year, Y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Y, x=Year, color=ID)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

**Plot**

[image]

**Problem**

In the case of the above plot, is there a way to use `gg_text()`, directlabels, or any other functions to automatically (rather than manually) label only the lines whose last point is `Y >= 50` (the purple and green lines) according to their IDs?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Just off the top of my head: you seem to know how to label _every_ line. Work backwards from that. Copy the ID column into some new variable. Modify that new column so that all the lines you don't want labelled have a blank "", or NA value maybe. Then maybe when you build labels using that column, only the ones you want will show something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the labels on the fly if you wish by filtering the data to get the appropriate label locations. For example:

```
ggplot(data=DATA, aes(Year, Y, color=ID)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_text(data=DATA %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
              arrange(desc(Year)) %>% 
              slice(1) %>% 
              filter(Y >= 50),
            aes(x = Year + 0.03, label=ID), hjust=0) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(colour=FALSE) +
  expand_limits(x = max(DATA$Year) + 0.03)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like that the labels match the line colors here

Comment: Neat! Slightly more dplyr-like  is to use `top_n(1, Year) %>%` instead of `arrange(desc(Year)) %>%  slice(1) %>%`

Comment: If anyone else is interested in this solution, I'll add that you can, of course, also add additional conditions to the filter functions in case it is picking up any points elsewhere where `Y >= 50`. For example, you can use `filter(Y >= 50 & Year == 2003)` to only pick up the rightmost points on each line.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest to add the labels into the data frame based on the condition, then plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
DATA %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(Y >= 50 & Year == max(Year), ID, NA)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Year, Y)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color = ID)) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = label))
```

[image]

Comment: I hadn't considered the mutate command. Thank you for the help!